# Caracter inválidos ao exportar para CSV Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Quando exporto um `DataGrid` para `.csv` os caracteres do meu `header` que contém acentos ficão com formatação inválida.

```
private function onExportToCSV():void
        {
            var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
            fileReference.save(DataGridDataExporter.exportCSV (dgLigacoes,';',';'),'LogLigacoes.csv');

        }
```

Comment: Isto provavelmente ocorre porque os dois estão com codificações diferentes.
Faça-os ter a mesma codificação: Ex: utf-8

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> já tem esta codificação